# Cartesian join in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to do a full Cartesian join using data.table but with little luck.

Code:

---

```
a = data.table(dt=c(20131017,20131018))
 setkey(a,dt)

 b = data.table(ticker=c("ABC","DEF","XYZ"),ind=c("MISC1","MISC2","MISC3"))
 setkey(b,ticker)
```

Expected output:

```
merge(data.frame(a),data.frame(b),all.x=TRUE,all.y=TRUE)
```

---

I have tried `merge(a,b,allow.cartesian=TRUE)` but it gives me following error -  "`Error in merge.data.table(a, b, allow.cartesian = TRUE) :   A non-empty vector of column names for`by`is required.`"

I am using "`R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)`" with latest `data.table` packages. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards

Comment: This looks more like an `expand.grid`-like problem than a `merge`-problem. You have no common variable.

Comment: The required output is achieved by Cartesian join using merge function but it works on data.frame and I am looking for a data.table solution if its possible.

Comment: I usually add a dummy variable, merge by that variable, and have `allow.cartesian = TRUE`. `CJ` and `expand.grid` can cross join vectors but I could never find a base function to create a cross-join of two tables. Can anybody point to such a function, if it exists?

Comment: @Codoremifa Yeah, I always just take the `CJ` or `expand.grid` of row numbers; never have found a better way. Here's an alternative, clumsy, solution: `data.table(merge.data.frame(a,b,all=TRUE))`.

Comment: As DWin points out, it is not really a `merge` operation. However to be compatible with `merge.data.frame`, I guess this functionality is required. Would you mind filing a feature request [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=978&group_id=240&func=browse)? Thank you.

Comment: Ok - Thanks for all the replies so far.

Codoremifa - The following code works:
-----
a = data.table(dt=c(20131017,20131018),dummy=1);
setkey(a,dummy);


b = data.table(ticker=c("ABC","DEF","XYZ"),ind=c("MISC1","MISC2","MISC3"),dummy=1);
setkey(b,dummy);

merge(a,b,allow.cartesian=TRUE);
------
still no luck with CJ(a,b);

@Arun - noted. I will submit a feature request today.

Answer (score 26):

I think a better solution is:

```
a[,as.list(b),by=dt]

         dt ticker   ind
1: 20131017    ABC MISC1
2: 20131017    DEF MISC2
3: 20131017    XYZ MISC3
4: 20131018    ABC MISC1
5: 20131018    DEF MISC2
6: 20131018    XYZ MISC3
```

Comment: This is very useful. I too couldn't get a cartesian join to work.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Codoremifa:

```
> dt <- c(20131017,20131018)
> b <- data.table(ticker=c("ABC","DEF","XYZ"), ind=c("MISC1","MISC2","MISC3"), key="ticker")
> b[CJ(ticker=ticker, dt=dt)][, c(3, 1, 2)]
         dt ticker   ind
1: 20131017    ABC MISC1
2: 20131018    ABC MISC1
3: 20131017    DEF MISC2
4: 20131018    DEF MISC2
5: 20131017    XYZ MISC3
6: 20131018    XYZ MISC3
```

Would be nicer if a single command would do it, but this is relatively straightforward.