# How to get top n distances by observation in a large dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I'm working with the Million Song Dataset, and I'm trying to get the closest 100 songs in Euclidean distance for each song, for a subset of about 237K songs. The code works below, but the RAM on my laptop only allows me to slice about 500 rows at a time so it'll be a LOT of copying and pasting. Any suggestions would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

```
tmp01 <- dist1 %>%
    slice(1:1000) %>%
    rename(track_id2 = track_id, artist_fam = artist_familiarity, 
        artist_hot = artist_hotttnesss, loud = loudness) %>%
    crossing(dist1) %>%
    mutate(dist_inv = 1 / ((artist_fam - artist_familiarity)^2 + 
            (artist_hot - artist_hotttnesss)^2 + (loud - loudness)^2)^.5) %>%
    filter(track_id != track_id2) %>%
    group_by(track_id2) %>%
    top_n(n = 100) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(track_id2, track_id, dist_inv) %>%
    mutate(dist = 1 / dist_inv) %>%
    arrange(track_id2, dist)
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` is more appropriate for voluminous data than `dplyr`. Operations will be faster and need less RAM if you apply the appropriate `data.table` verb, especially the `:=` operator. If you are not familiar with `data.table`, I recommend you the vignettes of the package.

The solution to avoid using `crossing̀` comes from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440769/cartesian-join-in-data-table/20645902). Not sure I got the merge key right: I guess you only want combinations of `track_id` with the same value on the left and right (because you do `filter(track_id != track_id2)` in your code) but give me some more details if it's not the case. To select the top *n* observations with `data.table`, you would use `dist1[,head(.SD, 100),by = "track_id2"]`

I can propose you the following code, that might need some adaptation because it is untested without reproducible example.

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(dist1)

setnames(dist1,
   old = c("track_id", "artist_familiarity","artist_hotttnesss","loudness"),
   new = c("track_id2","artist_fam", "artist_hot", "loud"))

dist1[,as.list(dist1),by="track_id"]

dist1[, dist_inv1 :=  1 / ((artist_fam - artist_familiarity)^2 + 
            (artist_hot - artist_hotttnesss)^2 + (loud - loudness)^2)^.5]

dist_agg <- dist1[,head(.SD, 100),by = "track_id2"]
dist_agg <- dist_agg[,.SD,.SDcols = c("track_id2", "track_id", "dist_inv")]
dist_agg[,dist := 1/dist_inv]
dist_agg <- dist_agg[order(track_id2, dist)]
```